# Envio WebService REINF - O servidor remoto retornou um erro: (500) Erro Interno do Servidor

Tags: web-service

Estou tentando me comunicar com o web service do **REINF** para enviar o evento de informações do contribuinte **(R-1000)**, entretanto estou recebendo o erro "**(500) Erro interno de Servidor**", na mensagem subjacente diz "Ocorreu um erro no processamento. Por favor tente novamente. Caso o problema persista, favor entrar em contato através do 'Fale Conosco' da EFD-REINF..., informe o problema e o número **[3033699826]**"

Alguém já passou por este erro? 

Desde já agradeço a atenção.

Abaixo a minha requisição e o retorno:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
   xmlns:sped="http://sped.fazenda.gov.br/">
   <soap:Header></soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <sped:ReceberLoteEventos>
         <sped:loteEventos>
            <Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/envioLoteEventos/v1_02_00">
               <loteEventos>
                  <evento id="ID1000000032343842018011517062000001">
                     <Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtInfoContribuinte/v1_02_00">
                        <evtInfoContri id="ID1000000032343842018011517062000001">
                           <ideEvento>
                              <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
                              <procEmi>1</procEmi>
                              <verProc>1.0</verProc>
                           </ideEvento>
                           <ideContri>
                              <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
                              <nrInsc>03234384</nrInsc>
                           </ideContri>
                           <infoContri>
                              <inclusao>
                                 <idePeriodo>
                                    <iniValid>2018-01</iniValid>
                                 </idePeriodo>
                                 <infoCadastro>
                                    <classTrib>13</classTrib>
                                    <indEscrituracao>1</indEscrituracao>
                                    <indDesoneracao>0</indDesoneracao>
                                    <indAcordoIsenMulta>0</indAcordoIsenMulta>
                                    <indSitPJ>0</indSitPJ>
                                    <contato>
                                       <nmCtt>LUCAS VALFRIDO COSTA.</nmCtt>
                                       <cpfCtt>21513643991</cpfCtt>
                                       <foneFixo>(042)32195250</foneFixo>
                                       <email>uniprime@uniprimecamposgerais.com.br</email>
                                    </contato>
                                 </infoCadastro>
                              </inclusao>
                           </infoContri>
                        </evtInfoContri>
                        <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                           <SignedInfo>
                              <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                              <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
                              <Reference URI="#ID1000000032343842018011517062000001">
                                 <Transforms>
                                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                                 </Transforms>
                                 <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                                 <DigestValue>KGsEYFOFJVca6JA5MnurDNJOOKXwElCopboz0oXegxg=</DigestValue>
                              </Reference>
                           </SignedInfo>
                           <SignatureValue>DPu5dR...5C1+jgQwbg==</SignatureValue>
                           <KeyInfo>
                              <X509Data>
                                 <X509Certificate>MIIH...E5+J6</X509Certificate>
                              </X509Data>
                           </KeyInfo>
                        </Signature>
                     </Reinf>
                  </evento>
               </loteEventos>
            </Reinf>
         </sped:loteEventos>
      </sped:ReceberLoteEventos>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Retorno (O servidor remoto retornou um erro: (500) Erro Interno do Servidor) Detalhe:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <faultcode>s:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">Ocorreu um erro no processamento. Por favor tente novamente. Caso o problema persista, favor entrar em contato através do 'Fale Conosco' da EFD - REINF - https://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/contato/fale-conosco/empresa/sped/efd-reinf-1 Ao entrar nessa página, clique em 'Indisponibilidade do Sistema', informe o problema e o número [3033699826] e anexe o XML do evento que foi objeto deste erro.</faultstring>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você está usando o `evtInfoContribuinte` (R-1000) na versão de leiaute **"v1_02_00"**, mas o ambiente de produção restrita do EFD-Reinf já está na versão **1.3.02**:

> Ambiente de Produção Restrita da EFD-REINF liberado
>   http://sped.rfb.gov.br/pagina/show/2641
>
> ESQUEMAS XSD - VERSÃO MAIS RECENTE
>   http://sped.rfb.gov.br/pasta/show/2270

Provavelmente o problema é esse.

Comment: Obrigado Pedro, havia pegado um exemplo de XML com uma versão anterior a atual,  infelizmente não era isso, peguei outro exemplo na versão atual e permanece o mesmo erro, mas ao menos estou partindo da versão correta agora. Obrigado.

Comment: Jeison, talvez o problema esteja nesse namespace **sped**, e nesses dois elementos, `sped:ReceberLoteEventos` e `sped:loteEventos`, que aparecem antes do primeiro elemento `Reinf`. Veja esse XML de exemplo (também está numa versão super defasada, mas, dá para ter uma ideia de como deveria ser), ele funcionou na época em que foi enviado: http://suporte.quarta.com.br/eSocial/arquivos/R1000_EnvioLote.xml

Answer (score 0):

Erro 500 normalmente se refere a permissões. Verifique se você possui permissão para acessar as informações, pastas ou diretórios. Veja mais no link:

[Erro 500](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500)

Comment: Obrigado Cristy, a principio não se trata de permissões. Mas obrigado pelo link.

Answer (score 0):

NÃO importa qual linguagem de programação, framework ou lib vc usa, faça o debug do XML da requisição usando o Postman.

Nesta pergunta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/407757/120972) eu explico como configurar e usar o Postman ( super simples ) e tb como usar e configurar o Fiddler.

O Fiddler serve para vc monitorar os dados das requisições que o seu app faz. Ao interceptar as requisições do seu app, vc tem a chance de comparar o que foi enviado contra o que deveria ter sido enviado.

O Fiddler é útil tb para capturar requisições de aplicações que tem a funcionalidade que vc quer implementar no seu app. O Fiddler é basicamente um Inspetor do Google Chrome/Firefox com a vantagem de capturar o request/response de tudo que tá no computador.

Tem também o [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/)

OBSERVAÇÕES:

- O Fiddler só será útil para monitorar as requisições. Enquanto o Fiddler estiver rodando, todas as requisições irão falhar retornando erro de permissão ( pois o Fiddler intercepta e re-envia a requisição SEM autenticar a comunicação );
- Para debuggar a resposta vc tem q desligar o Fiddler e usar o Postman. O Postman tb vai falhar se vc deixar o Fiddler rodando.