# EFD-Reinf via Postman -> Retorna erro MS0028 ("O parâmetro loteEventos não foi informado na chamada ao serviço")

Tags: soap, postman, web-service, soapclient

Eu estou usando o [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/) para compreender exatamente o que precisa ser enviado na requisição http.

**Autenticação:**

No programa Postman acessei o menu `Files -> Settings`, aba `Certificates` e informei o caminho dos arquivos .crt e .key.

No campo `Host` informei o valor `preprodefdreinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br`

Para criar os arquivos .crt e .key a partir do certificado .pfx eu usei os seguintes commandos:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -in yourfile.pfx -nocerts -out keyfile-encrypted.key
$ openssl pkcs12 -in yourfile.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out certificate.crt
```

**Dados da minha requisição:**

POST para https://preprodefdreinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/WsREINF/RecepcaoLoteReinf.svc

Headers:

```
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: http://sped.fazenda.gov.br/RecepcaoLoteReinf/ReceberLoteEventos
```

Body, selecione `raw` e `XML(text/xml)`. Conteúdo:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:hs="http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/envioLoteEventos/v1_04_00"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <loteEventos>
                <evento id="ID1236170070000002019090513234499999">
                    <Reinf>
                        <evtInfoContri id="ID1236170070000002019090513234499999">
                            <ideEvento>
                                <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
                                <procEmi>1</procEmi>
                                <verProc>test</verProc>
                            </ideEvento>
                            <ideContri>
                                <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
                                <nrInsc>23617007</nrInsc>
                            </ideContri>
                            <infoContri>
                                <inclusao>
                                    <idePeriodo>
                                        <iniValid>2019-01</iniValid>
                                    </idePeriodo>
                                    <infoCadastro>
                                        <classTrib>99</classTrib>
                                        <indEscrituracao>0</indEscrituracao>
                                        <indDesoneracao>0</indDesoneracao>
                                        <indAcordoIsenMulta>0</indAcordoIsenMulta>
                                        <indSitPJ>0</indSitPJ>
                                        <contato>
                                            <nmCtt>Some Idiot</nmCtt>
                                            <cpfCtt>53652495187</cpfCtt>
                                            <foneFixo>66535632196</foneFixo>
                                        </contato>
                                    </infoCadastro>
                                </inclusao>
                            </infoContri>
                        </evtInfoContri>
                            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                              <SignedInfo>
                                  <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm=" http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                                  <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                                  <Reference URI="#ID1236170070000002019090513234499999">
                                     <Transforms>
                                          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                                          <Transform Algorithm=" http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                                     </Transforms>
                                     <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                                     <DigestValue>...</DigestValue>
                                  </Reference>
                              </SignedInfo>
                              <SignatureValue>...</SignatureValue>
                              <KeyInfo>
                                  <X509Data>
                                      <X509Certificate>...</X509Certificate>
                                  </X509Data>
                              </KeyInfo>
                        </Signature>
                    </Reinf>
                </evento>
            </loteEventos>
        </Reinf>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Resposta do servidor:**

> Erro MS0028 - O parâmetro loteEventos não foi informado na chamada ao serviço

XML retornado:

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <ReceberLoteEventosResponse xmlns="http://sped.fazenda.gov.br/">
            <ReceberLoteEventosResult>
                <Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/retornoLoteEventos/v1_04_00">
                    <retornoLoteEventos id="IDA4CAC6F4F4C5A6BFE294A3CBB090B5C2">
                        <ideTransmissor>
                            <IdTransmissor>00000000000000</IdTransmissor>
                        </ideTransmissor>
                        <status>
                            <cdStatus>1</cdStatus>
                            <descRetorno>ERRO</descRetorno>
                            <dadosRegistroOcorrenciaLote>
                                <ocorrencias>
                                    <tipo>1</tipo>
                                    <codigo>MS0028</codigo>
                                    <descricao>O parâmetro loteEventos não foi informado na chamada ao serviço.</descricao>
                                </ocorrencias>
                            </dadosRegistroOcorrenciaLote>
                        </status>
                    </retornoLoteEventos>
                    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                        <SignedInfo>
                            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                            <Reference URI="#IDA4CAC6F4F4C5A6BFE294A3CBB090B5C2">
                                <Transforms>
                                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                                </Transforms>
                                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                                <DigestValue>...</DigestValue>
                            </Reference>
                        </SignedInfo>
                        <SignatureValue>...</SignatureValue>
                        <KeyInfo>
                            <X509Data>
                                <X509Certificate>...</X509Certificate>
                            </X509Data>
                        </KeyInfo>
                    </Signature>
                </Reinf>
            </ReceberLoteEventosResult>
        </ReceberLoteEventosResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**Perguntas:**

Parece que o parser do servidor NÃO está reconhecendo a tag `<loteEventos>` que estou enviando. Me parece ainda que há algo errado entre o começo do XML e a tag `<loteEventos>`.

Alguém consegue ver o que está errado no XML que estou enviando?

Tem como alguém usar um programa de monitoramento de tráfego, como o [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler-everywhere) por exemplo, capturar o corpo do body enviado por qualquer programa capaz de enviar EFD-Reinf, criar um gist no github e postar o link do gist nos comentários? Assim poderei comparar o seu XML contra o meu.

**Para configurar a interceptação HTTPS no Fiddler:**

Acesse https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/DecryptHTTPS para ver a documentação.

Na nova versão, acesse `Settings` ao invés de `Tools`. Aí basta selecionar `Capture HTTPS CONNECTs` e clicar em `Save Changes`. O botão `Export Root Certificate to Desktop` ficará disponível, clique nele para automaticamente importar o certificado raiz. Deste ponto em diante todo o tráfego via porta 443 (HTTPS) será descriptografado pelo Fiddler.

Comment: Francisco, na configuração do certificado no Postman você informou o valor `preprodefdreinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br` no campo *Host*? (https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/certificates) Você pode colocar o XML completo na pergunta? (oculte somente as informações privadas)

Comment: @PedroGaspar Sim, o valor do campo Host  consta `preprodefdreinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br`. Eu testei tentando enviar requisições SEM informar o certificado ou informando dados errados, o servidor retorna erro relacionado a permissões.

Comment: @PedroGaspar Eu alterei a pergunta acrescentando o XML completo que eu uso no Body. Acrescentei tb que é necessário selecionar `XML(text/xml)`. Com esse XML o servidor deveria retornar erro relacionado ao fato do XML NÃO está assinado.

Comment: E o elemento `Signature` que antes estava presente no XML de envio? Ele não está mais nessa edição. Também notei que a versão indicada no primeiro elemento `Reinf` foi alterada de `v1_04_00` (correta) para `v1_03_02` (errada). No segundo elemento `Reinf` seria interessante eliminar os atributos `xmlns:xsd` e `xmlns:xsi`. No elemento `evtInfoContri` use no atributo `id` o mesmo valor usado no elemento `evento`. No elemento `tpAmb` use o valor "2" (Produção Restrita). O CNPJ-base informado no elemento `nrInsc` deve ser o mesmo usado no atributo `id` dos elementos `evtInfoContri` e `evento`.

Comment: @PedroGaspar Muito obrigado pelo seu tempo. Eu alterei o XML da pergunta. Agora o XML de requisição reflete todas as suas sugestões. O servidor continua a retornar o mesmo erro. Me parece que a tag `<Signature>`, neste momento, é irrelevante pois o erro acusa que algo deu errado antes mesmo de alcançar o xml do evento sendo enviado. No momento em que tudo correr bem e o parser do servidor chegar à tag da assinatura, ai então retornaria algum erro relacionado a assinatura.

Comment: O parser do servidor NÃO está reconhecendo a tag `<loteEventos>` que estou enviando. Me parece que há algo errado entre a tag `<loteEventos>` e o começo do xml.

Comment: @PedroGaspar teria como vc, por favor, usar algum programa que monitora tráfico, como o fiddler caso use o Windows, e capturar o corpo do body enviado por qualquer programa que seja capaz de entregar EFD Reinf?

Comment: Acesse https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/DecryptHTTPS para ver como interceptar tráfego na porta 443 ( HTTPS ). É bem simples, basta selecionar `Capture HTTPS CONNECTs` e `Decrypt HTTPS traffic` e clicar no botão `Export Root Certificate to Desktop` para automaticamente importar o certificado raiz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na formatação do envelope, estava faltando o elemento raiz (no Body do SOAP) `ReceberLoteEventos` encapsulando o lote do EFD-Reinf.

O exemplo de envelope constante no [manual do desenvolvedor](http://sped.rfb.gov.br/pasta/show/2225), versão  1.4.01, página 16, está errado e incompleto.

Segue o modelo correto de envelope:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sped="http://sped.fazenda.gov.br/">
    <soapenv:Header />
    <soapenv:Body>
        <sped:ReceberLoteEventos>
            <sped:loteEventos>
                <Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/envioLoteEventos/v1_04_00">
                    <loteEventos>
                        <evento id="EVENTO_ID_AQUI">
                            <Reinf>
                                <!-- Resto do XML do evento aqui... -->
                            </Reinf>
                        </evento>
                    </loteEventos>
                </Reinf>
            </sped:loteEventos>
        </sped:ReceberLoteEventos>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Francisco, dessa forma funcionou? Estava faltando o elemento raiz (no Body) `ReceberLoteEventos`, antes do elemento `loteEventos`, não é? Eu nunca vejo o envelope SOAP porque uso o .NET e o envelopamento SOAP é criado automaticamente pelo framework.

Comment: @PedroGaspar Sim, desse jeito funciona. Antes de usar qualquer framework eu queria primeiro saber e entender exatamente o que é enviado.

Comment: Agora que eu compreendo que SOAP nada mais é que um simples POST com uma header a mais, agora eu consegui criar uma script com apenas 3 linhas de código, usando a lib https://github.com/Kong/unirest-php, para enviar os XMLs.

Comment: O PHP tem uma lib para SOAP, mas me parece que é muita complicação para algo que é essencialmente tão simples quanto um formulário web.

Comment: Que bom Francisco. Eu não sei dizer se o SOAP se limita a apenas isso, confesso que não tenho muito conhecimento nessa área, mas legal que você tenha ido mais a fundo nisso e detalhado no post. Você pode marcar a sua própria resposta como resposta, para ajudar outras pessoas que tenham a mesma dúvida no futuro. Eu só não entendi porque você disse na sua resposta que o exemplo no manual do desenvolvedor está incorreto.

Comment: @PedroGaspar eu inclui na resposta o link, a versão e a página do manual onde consta o exemplo de envelope que me refiro. O envelope do manual NÃO funciona e por isso o considero está errado e incompleto. Em relação ao SOAP, com certeza há muuuuuuito mais. O que eu quis dizer é que eu acho importante compreender o cerne da coisa. Em se tratando da transmissão das requisições, o SOAP é mais simples que o REST. O SOAP só usa o método POST, já o REST tem PUT, DELETE, PATCH, entre outros.

Comment: Ah sim, mas veja que nesse exemplo da pág. 16 o texto antes do exemplo é "*Exemplo **de uma** mensagem SOAP*", ou seja, é um exemplo genérico da estrutura de qualquer mensagem SOAP. O único exemplo de um XML do EFD-Reinf mesmo é o da página 20, e mesmo assim é só para demonstrar a parte da assinatura.

Comment: Eu NÃO consegui encontrar em nenhum lugar na documentação e NEM nos XSD informações que levassem a concluir que há a necessidade das tags `<sped:ReceberLoteEventos>` e `<sped:loteEventos>`. Sem falar que esses manuais técnicos de governos são escritos por gente com a mentalidade burocrata e, assim, são mal estruturados e, ao invés de esclarecer e orientar, causam confusão mental no leitor.